# Unterschied zwischen "wirken als ob" und "aussehen als ob"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> Es wirkt fast so, als habe Linklater (ein Name) das unauffälligste Kind gewählt, das
> er finden konnte.
>
> Mason (ein Name) selbst wirkt in jeder Szene, als sei er nie ganz da.

Er ist mir nicht klar, wo der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen und den folgenden liegt:

> Es sieht fast so aus, als habe Linklater (ein Name) das unauffälligste Kind gewählt, das
> er finden konnte.
>
> Mason (ein Name) selbst sieht in jeder Szene aus, als sei er nie ganz da.

Kann jemand erklären, was der Sprecher empfindet, um einen Ausdruck  oder den anderen zu wählen? (Dabei ist das Worterbuch nicht behilflich gewesen).

```
    Die beiden Beispiele kommen aus einem Artikel in der Zeitung "DIE ZEIT", der
    über einen Film spricht.
```

Answer (score 5):

"Wirken" is about the effect you have on someone. And that can come from anything... appearance, voice, gestures etc.
A good translation is:

> You seem tired.

"aussehen" is about your looks specifically.

> You look tired.

In your examples, the verbs are also used with the generic "es". Since this "es" has no real looks, the verbs are indeed quite close in these phrasings I would translate them both as

> it seems

But for the second part of your examples, it's definitely a difference between just looking a certain way and coming across a certain way (which can be based on looks too, but not necessarily)

For a more detailed look at the verbs you can check out my blog posts on ["wirken"](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/meaning-wirken/) and ["aussehen"](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/meaning-aussehen/).

Comment: Dies hier ist ein Forum über die deutsche Sprache, und die Frage wurde in Deutsch gestellt. Warum also antwortest du nicht auf Deutsch sondern auf Englisch? Der Fragesteller kommt aus Barcelona (in Spanien). Ohne weitere Informationen ist unklar ob er überhaupt Englisch gut genug beherrscht um deine Antwort zu verstehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... ich hab' einfach nicht aufgepasst. Ich hab' die Frage gelesen, dann war ich kurz woanders und dann hab' ich sie beantwortet. Du kannst es gerne übersetzen. Ich bin aber sehr sicher, dass OP gut genug Englisch kann, denn er/sie hat die gleiche Frage auf meinem Blog gestellt, und der ist in Englisch

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, Emanuel. Ich finde deinen Blog sehr interessant, ein Meisterwerk, aber ich habe darauf keine Frage gestellt.

Comment: @Calogero... OOOOPS.. stimmt, das war die andere Frage hier mit "drehen vs. umdrehen". Da hab ich voll was verwechselt. Sorry für die Englische Antwort. Ich hab's einfach verpeilt.

Comment: @Hubert - I don't think there's anything wrong with posting (either asking or answering) in English. My German, for instance, is good enough to understand, but not good enough to write, so except for very simple questions I have to post in English, although I appreciate answers in German. If an OP wants his answers in German because of limited understanding of English, IMO he should say so. If he doesn't both English and German are allowed.

Comment: @stevenvh: If an OP asks in a German language board a question in German language (and when, in addition, he is coming from a country where English is not an official language), then I don't see any reason to post answers in English. What if someone had posted the answer in Turkish or Chinese? Would this be ok? Why is English ok, but any other Language not - in a GERMAN LANGUAGE board?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... generally I do agree with you but the menu-items of the site are indeed in English, so English is not that far fetched

Comment: @Hubert - This board is a special case, but the lingua franca on stackexchange is English. But naturally you can expect posts in German on this board, I have no problem with either. But are you saying that I shouldn't be allowed to answer a German question in English, just because my German isn't good enough to write a correct answer?

Comment: @Hubert - Also note that the name of the site is "German language", not "Deutsche Sprache".